# How to unify SQL COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have this code and I want to minimize it, but nothing is working to me:

```
SELECT(SELECT COUNT(nes) FROM general_list WHERE nes<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(snes) FROM general_list WHERE snes<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(msx2) FROM general_list WHERE msx2<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(gb) FROM general_list WHERE gb<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(gc) FROM general_list WHERE gc<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(gba) FROM general_list WHERE gba<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(ds) FROM general_list WHERE ds<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(ds3) FROM general_list WHERE ds3<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(wii) FROM general_list WHERE wii<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(pc) FROM general_list WHERE pc<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(ps1) FROM general_list WHERE ps1<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(ps2) FROM general_list WHERE ps2<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(ps3) FROM general_list WHERE ps3<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(ps4) FROM general_list WHERE ps4<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(psp) FROM general_list WHERE psp<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(wsc) FROM general_list WHERE wsc<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(x360) FROM general_list WHERE x360<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%')+
(SELECT COUNT(xone) FROM general_list WHERE xone<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%') AS SumCount;
```

I tried to use SELECT nes,snes,msx2.......,COUNT(*) and also to put the columns inside COUNT (SELECT COUNT(nes,snes.....)...), but both of them won't work :(

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean "won't work"?  Are you getting an SQL error?  Or is the count not returning what you would expect?

Comment: The COUNT is returning a number I don't expect.
But in COUNT(nes,snes...) the query won't work.

Comment: Have you considered using the `DISTINCT` keyword in your subqueries?  Are you trying to count the instances of (for example) the nes records, or just to verify if the nes exists?  If you are aiming for the latter, then use DISTINCT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation.  Here is a start:

```
SELECT (COUNT(CASE WHEN nes <> 0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%' THEN nes END) +
        COUNT(CASE WHEN snes<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%' THEN snes END) +
        COUNT(CASE WHEN msx2<>0 AND saga LIKE '%/FFI/%' THEN msx2 END) +
        . . .
       ) as SumCount
FROM general_list;
```

Given that the `saga` piece is all the same, you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT (COUNT(CASE WHEN nes <> 0 THEN nes END) +
        COUNT(CASE WHEN snes <> 0 THEN snes END) +
        COUNT(CASE WHEN msx2 <> 0 THEN msx2 END) +
        . . .
       ) as SumCount
FROM general_list
WHERE saga LIKE '%/FFI/%' ;
```

And, this, in turn, can probably be simplified using `sum()`:

```
SELECT (SUM(nes <> 0) +
        SUM(snes <> 0) +
        SUM(msx2 <> 0) +
        . . .
       ) as SumCount
FROM general_list
WHERE saga LIKE '%/FFI/%' ;
```

MySQL treats booleans as integers, with `1` being true.  So using `SUM()` counts the number of matching values.